# VBA Macros for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute a program in which the program gets the data from a workbook to a different workbook, but I get a `runtime-9-error`. Please Help me.

```
Sub cutex3()
    'between 2 sheets in two different workbooks
    Workbooks("book2").Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1 : A5").Cut _
    Workbooks("book3").Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1 : A5")
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me... BTW Do you need to use `Cut`? Or `Copy` would also do?

Comment: Check that you have workbooks and sheets with those actual names. A `runtime error 9 - subscript out of range` means that you don't.

Comment: @DougGlancy: True that :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: right now iam using cut.

Answer (score 0):

> but i get a runtime-9-error

The code that you gave above works for me but since you are getting `Run-time error 9` that means it's a `Subscript out of range` Error.

Please ensure that you have the following

1. Workbook named `book2`
2. Workbook named `book3`
3. Worksheet named `sheet2` in `book2`
4. Worksheet named `sheet3` in `book3`

Comment: ya i entered everything correctly. but it still throws the error

Comment: check if the names of the worksheet or the workbook do not have any spaces and also workbooks are not opened in separate excel instances...

Comment: i have two workbooks created separately. but i dont know to create it in a single file. please guide me.however the vba editor(alt+f11) shows me two workbooks in the project explorer.

Comment: then it is in the same instance. can u zip and upload the workbooks to a file sharing site and share the link here? posting from phone so ignore typos please...

Comment: please check this link [link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g1e6e9c4e7cac4be5999391274374563d9ca69addf)

Comment: I just tested it and it works just fine for me. How are you opening the 2nd workbook? Manually? What happens if you open it via code?

Comment: please check this link. i have uploaded the screen(video).[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRAdl4Aqi8M)